# Небольшое объяснение от Вас о том, как это делают спецы. Вывод на страницу базу данных и пополнение ее там же

Tags: php, html, mysql, база-данных

расскажите, как обычно это делается? Опишите мне сам процесс?

Имеются несколько пользователей, они обрабатывают текстовые файлы. У каждого своя база данных из 3 столбцов (id, Найти в строке, Заменить найденное на другое значение). Должна быть дополнительная страница, где выведется таблица и там же нужно ее пополнять новыми значениями. Ячейки тогда делать `<textarea>`, я правильно понял? Чтобы пользователю зайти и пополнить таблицу, нужно просто сделать страницу, на которую проходить по ссылке, так ведь? Ну тогда у каждого пользователя должен быть свой адрес этой страницы. Как это сделать?

Как вообще выводить таблицы нужного пользователя?  А если представить, что данные пользователя (имя и пароль) хранятся тоже в базе? Как базы данных пользователей соединены с базами данных "Найти-заменить"?

Спасибо!

Comment: голосую за закрытие вопроса, ибо он слишком общий, для начала начните изучение php и предметной области

Answer (score 4):

Спецы всегда начинают с того, что пытаются разобраться в предметной области, с которой предстоит работать. Для начала они изучают общепринятую терминологию, читая документацию и искусно применяя гуглёж. Если спецы чувствуют, что им не хватает опыта для понимания нагугленного, они обращаются к [урокам для новичков](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20%D0%B8%20mysql%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85).

Например, они читают документацию mysql и выясняют, что из столбцов состоят не базы а таблицы; что столбцы имеют тип, и типа textarea нет, а есть *varchar* (и другие строковые типы); узнают о возможности задать условия выборки с помощью *where*.

Спецы внимательно изучают примеры и начинают догадываться, что можно создать таблицу пользователей и у каждого пользователя будет идентификатор, тогда этот идентификатор можно добавить к строкам из таблицы правок (получится: id, Найти в строке, Заменить найденное на другое значение, **userId**). Тогда получение правок конкретного пользователя будет реализовано следующим образом:

```
select * from `corrections` where `uerId` = :id
```

*Аутентификация пользователя* -- отдельная история, которую тоже следует внимательно изучить.

Когда ситуация проясняется, спецы приступают к реализации задуманного.

Comment: Насчет <textarea>. Я писал не про тип textarea, а о том, если нужно там же заполнять базу данных, тогда пользователь будет значения вписывать в <textarea> (или <input>)? То есть, каждая ячейка будет состоять из <textarea>?

Comment: @forever_young это уж как вам нужно. `textarea` позволяет вводить переносы строк и более удобна, если редактируется относительно большой кусок текста. Если вам переносы строк не нужны, то можно использовать `input type="text"`.